# Remove elements from a list in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to remove a particular value from within a list in the pandas dataframe column. How do I go about this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
               'B': [['b1', 'b2'], ['b1', 'b1'], ['b2']],
               'C': [['c1', 'b1'], ['b3'], ['b2', 'b2']],
               'D': ['d1', 'd2', 'd3']})
```

I want to remove the string 'b1' in lists from the column 'B' in the dataframe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove string value from column in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33413249/how-to-remove-string-value-from-column-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: That solution requires converting the entire column to string.

Comment: I see that you are asking similar questions. Any reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use list comprehension

```
df['B'] = df.B.apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i != 'b1'])


    A   B       C           D
0   a1  [b2]    [c1, b1]    d1
1   a2  []      [b3]        d2
2   a3  [b2]    [b2, b2]    d3
```

Comment: What is the error message or what is the output that you are getting?

Comment: Please, if I would like to remove more than one element from a list at once, what could I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Like all my previous answers

```
(df.B.map(set)-{'b1'}).map(list)
Out[171]: 
0    [b2]
1      []
2    [b2]
Name: B, dtype: object
```

Comment: But would also kill duplicates of other string elements, which is not the case here, but since for "b1" the case, so maybe also possible for the other strings.

Comment: For a concrete example replace in the dataframe the column B so: 'B': [['b1', 'b2'], ['b1', 'b1'], ['b2']] 
with: 'B': [['b1', 'b2', 'b2'], ['b1', 'b1'], ['b2', 'b2']]