# how to remove items of Dataframe from list

Tags: python, dataframe

I have `dataframe` like this

```
dataframe = {}
    'Sentence #': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3]
    'Word': ['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b']
    'POS': ['NNS', 'RB', 'CD','NNS', 'RB', 'CD','NNS', 'RB']
    'Tag': ['B-PRO', 'I-DR', 'O', 'B-PRO', 'I-DR', 'O', 'B-PRO', 'I-DR']
}
```

now I want to remove some of them from `List` like:

```
remove_list = [1,3]
```

I want to remove all `sentence-word-pos-tag` related to `sentence-number` like this:

```
'Sentence #': [1,1,1,3,3]
'POS': ['NNS', 'RB', 'CD','NNS', 'RB']
'Tag': ['B-PRO', 'I-DR', 'O', 'B-PRO', 'I-DR']
```

Comment: Where is `Word`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove elements from a list in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53889227/remove-elements-from-a-list-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: did you try to filter your dataframe on Sentence # ?

Comment: It seems that `remove_list = [1,3]` is a list with the values you want to keep

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(dataframe)
result=df[~df['Sentence #'].isin(remove_list)]
```